C# Extracting Data From Trained Model (ITransformer LastTransformer)
I have a model being trained with Microsoft.ML.
I'm having difficulty transferring the model file (ITransformer trainedModel)
to a FastTreeRegressionModelParameters to get the Weights
The problem I have is:
trainedModel.LastTransformer.Model  >>
ITransformer does not contain the definition "LastTransformer"
and also
FastTreeRegressionModelParameters does not contain FeatureWeights
public async Task TrainAndEvaluateModelAsync(string inputFilePath, string modelFilePath)
{

_mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile\<DataClass\>(inputFilePath, hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ' '));

Console.WriteLine("Data loaded successfully.");

        Console.WriteLine("Defining pipeline...");  
      
        var trainedModel = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

        Console.WriteLine("Model trained successfully.");   
 
        AnalyzeTrainingData(trainingData, trainedModel);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
private void AnalyzeTrainingData(IDataView trainingData, ITransformer trainedModel)
{
    // Feature Importance
    var featureImportance = trainedModel.LastTransformer.Model as FastTreeRegressionModelParameters;
    if (featureImportance != null)
    {
        var weights = featureImportance.FeatureWeights;
        Console.WriteLine("Feature Importance:");
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Feature {i}: {weights[i]}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Model does not support feature weights retrieval.");
    }
}

Error   CS1061  'ITransformer' does not contain a definition for 'LastTransformer' and no accessible extension method 'LastTransformer' accepting a first argument of type 'ITransformer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS1061  'FastTreeRegressionModelParameters' does not contain a definition for 'FeatureWeights' and no accessible extension method 'FeatureWeights' accepting a first argument of type 'FastTreeRegressionModelParameters' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

not sure how to convert from the model to an array of features, tries using the mlContext, and a few other things with no success
